# Hand base position in Leap Motion

Tags: leap-motion

I want to know whether it is possible to find Hand's base position in Leap Motion...

I am confused with the Hand base position. Or should I continue with the Hand Sphere Center.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hand.palmPosition(), located at the center of the palm, is the closest point given by the LM API to the base of the palm. I'd use that rather than the sphereCenter(), which would be somewhere below the palm and may move less predictably as the user flexes their fingers.

[Update]
Since version 2.0 of the Leap Motion SDK, the Hand class has a wristPosition() attribute.

Comment: Thanks again Charles, I found the answer few hours later posting the question.